# .find() doesn't execute its block on an empty list in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

so today I stumbled on an interesting bug and I wanted to ask the reason why. I have the following:

```
val phone = contactDAO.phones?.find {
    val phone = it.content
    phone != null && !phone.startsWith("+")
} != null
if (phone) {...}
```

so yes phones could be null but it can also be empty. 
It seems kotlin sees that is not null and goes to the .find
but realizes is empty and thus never executes the block inside.
why is this?
and is there a cleaner way to do this check along with .find?

Comment: What result do you expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple example.

```
@JvmStatic
fun main(arr: Array<String>) {
    val array = emptyArray<String>()
    val foundItem = array.find {
        it == "String" // This will never call
    }
    println(foundItem)
}
```

If your array is empty, find predicate condition will never call. This is no reason to call.

Comment: thanks! what happens is that 1. I didn't know block doesn't get executed and it returns null. Since I had a last check null != null this always accounted to false but this doesn't account for an empty list.

Answer (score 0):

It already simple enough, you don't need to check for `null` in the predicate.

**Example**

```
val phones: List<String>? = listOf("1", "2", "+3", "4", "5")
println(phones?.find { it.startsWith("+") })
```

**Output**

```
+3
```

**Example**

```
val phones: List<String>? = null
println(phones?.find { it.startsWith("+") })
```

**Output**

```
null
```

Also just a head up, `find` will only match the first element or `null` if none is found, maybe you are most interested in `filter`, that returns a `List` with all the matching elements

Comment: yeah, I realized that I forgot to add the end of the block where I have a null comparison. So since evaluated to true it always doing the wrong action.

Comment: @Beto With the last change, you are just creating a `Boolean` variable, it doesn't make a lot of sense